# PowerBI on demand report/dataset generation

Tags: powerbi

Perhaps better to rephrase my question.

If I have a powerbi report..
Can I somehow make copies of this report with different data(set?) via an API and on demand?

e.g.
User requests a report with some parameters,
Existing report gets copies with a new dataset and published

tnx
Brian

== origional question below ==

Would anyone be able to point in in the right direction here.

I currently have a c# application that generates reports which are simply excel files.
Each time I create a report I simply open an excel file with some preexisting formatting, set the data in a particular sheet then save it to a new location.

How can I achieve something similar with PowerBI?

Ideaily I'd like to open a precanned powerbi report, pass a parameter to the 'dataset' I've just generated,

I dont have any string feeling as to what the dataset would be, I'm open to whatever works,
database/static dataset created by csharp somehow/webservice/etc.

Can anyone suggest how? tnx

Answer (score 1):

How about creating you Power BI report based on your existing Excel files? Make sure to store them on SharePoint so that the PowerBI Online Service can pick them up w/o additional gateways. You can then use your app to trigger the report refresh as soon as the Excel files have been updated.

Comment: hi peter, tnx for your comment.

if i understand correctly, i can have a report refresh when an excel file is updated, I hadn't considered this tnx.

however over the last hour, I may have 10 excel files generated for each user in the system, i somehow need to generate a seperate report for each one

i'm basically looking to generate a uniquie report for a specific filter/query and retrieve same at a later date.

to say it another way, 
I want to let a user define a query and anytime he clicks a button, to generate a report based on this query against data in the system